# Apache - handling TCP connections, but not HTTP requests

Tags: php, apache, tcp

I have a GPS unit that can send data over a TCP connection, but I don't have the ability to modify the message that it sends so it would come to my server in the form of an HTTP request - it can only send a message in a predefined format.

So, I have the following questions:

1) Is it possible to have Apache handle a TCP connection that doesn't come in the form of an HTTP request, and have the message that is sent be processed by a PHP script?

2) If #1 isn't possible, how would you recommend I handle the data being sent to my server?

I will potentially have hundreds, if not thousands, of these GPS units sending data to my server so I need an efficient way to handle all of the connections coming in (which is why I wanted Apache or some other production worthy server to handle the TCP connections). I would like to be able to deal with the message sent over the connection with PHP since that is what the rest of my application runs on, and I will need to insert the data sent into a database (and PHP is really good at doing that kind of thing).

In case it matters, the GPS unit can send data over a UDP connection, but from what I have read Apache doesn't work with UDP connections.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Apache wouldn't be practical as it's using a nuclear bomb when a firecracker will suffice. Creating a PHP server is quite simple on Linux with the help of xinetd.

**Modify `/etc/services`.** Say you want your service to run on port 56789. In `/etc/services`, add the line:

```
gpsservice   56789/tcp
```

**In `/etc/xinet.d/`, create a file named `gpsservice`:**

```
service gpsservice 
{
    socket_type             = stream
    protocol                = tcp
    wait                    = no
    user                    = yourusername
    server                  = /path/to/your/script
    log_on_success          = HOST PID
    disable                 = no
}
```

**Create your PHP script (chmod it to be executable):**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// do stuff
?>
```

**Restart xinetd `service xinetd restart`**

You now have a quick TCP server written in PHP.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into this. Quick question though - what would it take to make this work with UDP connections? And, would this simple solution handle thousands of requests an hour?

Comment: You could change `tcp` to `udp` in the service file and gpsservice file. It's not recommended to use UDP as it can be an unreliable protocol: http://www.mindcontrol.org/~hplus/udp-vs-tcp.html

Comment: Just a heads up, there are no TCP port numbers beyond 65535.

Comment: @webbiedave can you please provide a sample for getting data over tcp in php. I am trying but it is not working properly :( this is what the code looks like:-----------------------------------------  #!/usr/bin/php 
<?php
$handle = fopen('php://stdin','r');
$input = fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);
$datatxt = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9,*.]+/", "", $input);
$time=date("U");
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
$SQL ="INSERT into table (text,time) values('$datatxt','$time')"; 
$conn->query($SQL) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$conn->close();
die();
?>-------------------------

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1) Not without major modification

2) Build your own server.  This is easily done with several platforms and in several languages.  I personally like to use the [Twisted Framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) because Python is relatively simple to use and the framework is very flexible.