# How to make apache process TCP connections?

Tags: php, apache, sockets, tcp, subdomain

I have a problem that is stuck in my mind for almost 24 hours, and at this moment I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the thing: I want to have one 'main' socket on my server that processes all incoming data and sends it to other clients using PHP. That part goes fine, but I want to connect with that socket using multiple subdomains, e.g. ex.example.com. The thing with this is, that you cannot connect with that subdomain unless you have a socket running on it, and that just fills up your ports and that is what I'm trying to prevent.

The best solution is to make Apache process the incoming TCP request, saves the data on which domain you are connecting, and then redirects the client to the main socket, which processes the received data and immediately acts when the client is accepted.

Honestly, I have no idea how to do this. I'm searching for hours, but the only thing I've found was something on Stackoverflow that got close to it: [Apache - handling TCP connections, but not HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917167/apache-handling-tcp-connections-but-not-http-requests)

But with that piece of script I am not able to save data (which domain you're using) and send it to the main socket.

I don't know if this can be done by Apache or if it is possible at all, or if there are any other workarounds.

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do. Sockets don't "run on a subdomain". Domain names map to IPs. When handling HTTP requests, Apache uses 'Host' HTTP/1.1 header to tell one virtual host from another. With raw TCP you either have to use separate IP for each subdomain, or send desired subdomain name in your custom protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused about subdomains.  Sockets, TCP, and IP all know *absolutely nothing* about names.  DNS wasn't invented until that networking stack had been around for years.

Thus, you can point any number of domains at a single "socket" port on a machine.

Apache can route an incoming request to different "webspaces" (i.e. virtual hosts) based on the destination IP address of the incoming connection(1) or the HTTP/1.1 "Host" header(2).  The former was how virtual hosts used to be done but now almost everybody uses the latter.

(1) A machine can have multiple IP addresses even with a single network card but ports are unique to any given protocol on that machine.  You point different domains to different addresses and define a reverse-mapping on the webserver so it can tell how the request began.

(2) The value of the "host" is the DNS name that was given to the browser.  Since this value is passed explicitly to the webserver, that server doesn't need to rely on tricks like #1.